# Cordova network isOnline returns true only on WiFi

Tags: cordova, meteor, ngcordova

The following logs out only when I have WiFi on. On 4g or any mobile internet type it doesn't. Doesn't seem so reliable. Any ideas for a better detection of online/offline state?

```
$rootScope.$on( '$cordovaNetwork:online', function ( event, networkState ) {
    console.log( "Phone is online" );
} );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
function isOnline(){
     return !(Connection.NONE==navigator.connection.type);
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: But what about the UNKNOWN state?