# Cordova navigator.connection only unknown or wifi

Tags: android, cordova

I used [this](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/) to check if the device is online or offline.

However, on my new `OnePlusX` with `Android 5.1.1` i'm facing a weird behaviour.
`$cordovaNetwork.isOnline()` is always false if i'm not using wifi. Even if i have internet connection.

I checked `$cordovaNetwork.getNetwork()` and `navigator.connection.type` and if i'm not in a wifi, i always get `unknown` (`Connection.UNKNOWN`) . If i'm in a wifi i get `wifi`(`Connection.WIFI`).

I already tried to remove the android platform and re-add it again, but without success.

```
$ ionic --version
1.7.10

$ cordova --version
5.4.1
```

Comment: Please, take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878872/cordova-network-isonline-returns-true-only-on-wifi/33879169#33879169

Comment: Yeah i already thought of that, but i'm not so sure if it is a good thing, that i ignore the Connection.UNKNOWN state.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem