# $cordovaNetwork returns false even if I am connected

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am using `$cordovaNetwork` to know when my project is connected to network and when not. I am using the method `isOnline()`, and it returns false. But it is not true, because I know I am connected when the device is ready. I have some information that I catch from internet that is loaded in the beginning, so I have connection to internet.

When the event online is fired up? When `$cordovaNetwork` knows really that the application is online? Sometimes it shows me that there is connection (TRUE) but sometimes it shows me that there isn't (FALSE).

Finally, I use that application, so I have change the state, and then `$cordoaNetwork.isonline()` returns me FALSE, very strange.

Can any one help me? The documentation is not very extensive. And If you can, give some example, please. If need more information, ask me.

thanks

Comment: can you show some code please, also which device you are running app on.. is it running on real device or is it just a simulated one

Comment: Take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878872/cordova-network-isonline-returns-true-only-on-wifi/33879169#33879169

Comment: I have exactly the same problem

Answer (score 1):

If your `navigator.connection.type` is `Connection.UNKNOWN`, the `$cordovaNetwork.isOnline()` always return `false`, even if you are already online.

I think this is mistake of ngCordova

the `ngCordova` source

```
isOnline: function () {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    return networkState !== Connection.UNKNOWN && networkState !== Connection.NONE;
},

isOffline: function () {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    return networkState === Connection.UNKNOWN || networkState === Connection.NONE;
},
```

You need overwrite `isOnline` and `isOffline` function.

overwrite in `app.run` section,

```
$cordovaNetwork.isOnline = function () {
    return navigator.connection.type !== Connection.NONE;
};
$cordovaNetwork.isOffline = function () {
    return navigator.connection.type === Connection.NONE;
};
```

I hope for your help

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try your solution this night. And I say to you if I still have the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done the next steps:

Open a terminal and write "nvm use v4.2.3" to have the correct version of nodejs active.
Go to the folder of project, in my case, "cd /var/phone/myProject"
Write "ionic run android".
Wait some seconds until the application is up.

Until here, I don't have problems. The application is built well. Then, I use $cordovaNetwork in order to monitoring the states of online and offline, when is active in a moment. $cordovaNetwork.isOnline() works, but It appears that sometimes don't know when one state or another is really active. All the times that I run the application, I know that is connected because some of the code is in a server, so if it is not loaded, it will appear blank.

So knowing that the event online is active, why $cordovaNetwork.isOnline() doesn't detect it? I was looking for the solution in other forums, but it appears that nobody has had this problem.

And yes, I am emulating the application, perhaps the problem is in the emulator? Before I use the command "ionic run android", I have to open other terminal and write "android avd" to have a platform of android open to use the application. I have not tested it in a phone.

Thanks for your help. And jcarrera, I see the post you share, but I need to use $cordovaNetwork directly, not using navigator.connection.type, where navigator is used when the application is running through a browser. Anyway, I prove it, but I think that it is moreless the same as in this [post](http://www.joshmorony.com/monitoring-online-and-offline-states-in-an-ionic-application/).
Thanks for your help

Comment: I have exactly the same problem